# Flutter Dart OOP programming basics - text from one class to another

Tags: android, flutter, class, oop, dart

I am **extremely new** to Flutter. I've followed tons of tutorials.....
And now, I am trying to build my own **Calculator App**. I am having problems with ***OOP with dart***.

I have **built the Frontend(UI)** for my **one-page** Calculator app.

[image]

## **Here are the three code files:**

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'calculator_button_layout.dart';
import 'calculator_button.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Magic Calculator"),
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[850],
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.green,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Text(
                      "0",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CalculatorButtonLayout()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### calculator_button.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class CalculatorButton extends StatefulWidget {
      final String text;
      final Color color;
      final int flex;
    
      CalculatorButton({this.text, this.color, this.flex});
    
      @override
      _CalculatorButtonState createState() => _CalculatorButtonState();
    }
    
    class _CalculatorButtonState extends State<CalculatorButton> {
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Expanded(
          flex: this.widget.flex,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20)),
              color: this.widget.color,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(this.widget.text,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ))),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

### calculator_button_layout.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'calculator_button.dart';

class CalculatorButtonLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "C",
                color: Colors.red[800],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "+/-",
                color: Colors.red[800],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "%",
                color: Colors.red[800],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "/",
                color: Colors.red[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "1",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "2",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "3",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "*",
                color: Colors.red[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "4",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "5",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "6",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "+",
                color: Colors.red[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "7",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "8",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "9",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "-",
                color: Colors.red[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "0",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 2,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: ",",
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
              CalculatorButton(
                text: "=",
                color: Colors.red[900],
                flex: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

## MY PROBLEM:

---

How can I send the **this.widget.text** as String to **Text()** in *main.dart* as I push the buttons on the calculator!
I have looked at all the questions related to **"How to get data from one class to the other in flutter"**. But have found Navigator.push() being used... But the problem is that My app is a one-pager

Comment: If you could please explain this in more detail(with all code) in the answer section by giving an edit with new heading. Then I will mark you answer as accepted as I feel more comfortable with using setState() as no external package is uesd. @dhananjay-gavali –

Comment: If you could please explain this in more detail(with all code) in the answer section by giving an edit with new heading. Then I will mark you answer as accepted as I feel more comfortable with using setState() as no external package is uesd. @dhananjay-gavali –

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve it.
The problem is you have to update the value of `Text()` in `main.dart` `ontap` of `calculatorButton`.

Using setState is one of the option. But as your `calculatorButton` and `Home`  are two seprate classes using setState can be complicated to use.

I will use Provider for this data handling.

you can install package from here: https://pub.dev/packages/provider/install

get the package in `pubspec.yaml`

Providers automatically updates the values of variables without calling build method again and again.

Basically you will create a new class like the following.

```
class TextValue with ChangeNotifier{
String inputvalue;

get getTextvalue => inputvalue;

void setTextValue(String value){
this.inputvalue = value;
notifyListener();
}

}
```

`notifyListener()` will notify the all the widgets that the value of the variable is changed and you need to rebuild. so every time you will tap on the button and call `setTextValue(value)` method it will rebuild the `text` widget in `main.dart` and value will be updated.

In order to use it you need to Create a provider in your main method.
`Provider` is like the Superclass that will pass down the data to it's subclasses.
So to pass the data in all your app we will wrap `MaterialApp` inside the `provider` and create a `provider` with our `TextValue` class. Like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => TextValue(),
child: MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
  ),
),
);
}
```

`ChangeNotifierProvider` is type of provider which is used to notify on value change. you can find lot's of tutorials on this.

Now how to call this method and get the updated value in the `main.dart`.

Lets first check how to call this method:

**Caculator_button.dart**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: this.widget.flex,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
Provider.of<TextValue>(context, listen:false).setTextValue(this.widget.text);

},
```

This will called the method inside provider. and notify it's childrens.

Now how to use this value.

**In Main.dart inside your container**

```
Container(
                  //color: Colors.green,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Text(
//call the getter using provider
                      Provider.of<TextValue>(context, listen: false).getTextvalue,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

That's it.
Also further you can Use `consumer` widget provided by `provider`. You can find out it in documentation.

Comment: could you plz explain for setState() as well. @dhananjay-gavali

Comment: For using `setState()` you need to create some getters and methods that will return the value on every tap and then you will call those `methods` or `getters` inside the `setState()` in `main.dart` as your output field exists there. suppose your getter is `getRecentTapValue` so you create one variable  like `value / output` and set it as a value to your output field. Then inside setState() you can initialize that output variable like `this.value` =  `getRecentTapValue()`. so it will build your ui again and value will be set for output. but provider is efficient as it only builds what's require

Comment: If you could please explain this in more detail(with all code) in the answer section by giving an edit with new heading. Then I will mark you answer as accepted as I feel more comfortable with using setState() as no external package is uesd. @dhananjay-gavali

Answer (score -1):

Although there are many ways to transfer information from one place to other, your usecase is very simple so I'll suggest the simplest solution to you.

### Callbacks

You can use the power of callbacks. These are just functions declared in the parent and passed as variables down to the child. The function can be executed from inside the child to manipulate data inside the parent. Your solution would be like this.

---

### Creating callbacks

1. Inside **calculator_button.dart**, add another attribute like so:

```
final void Function(String) onPressed;
```

2. Inside onPressed of the **TextButton** widget pass it the text value like so:

```
onPressed: (){
 widget.onPressed(widget.text);
}
```

This calls the function provided by the parent, passing it's text value which can then be used inside our parent i.e `main.dart`

---

### Passing callbacks

Since you've refactored your widgets you'll have to pass the callback down the tree through multiple constructors, which is one of the downsides of not using `dependency injection`.

1. Inside **calculator_layout.dart**, we'll create a attribute just we did before:

```
final void Function(String) buttonCallback;
```

2. Pass this attribute to each of the button:

```
CalculatorButton(
    onPressed: buttonCallback,
    ...
),
```

---

### Declaring callbacks

Finally we're going to provide the body for our callback, this is done inside the parent widget.

1. Inside **main.dart**, we want to update the text to the new string so we need to convert our `Home` widget to stateful widget.
2. Create a variable inside the state to store the text:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> { //<-- Convert to stateful like this
final displayText = "0"; //<-- Add this state variable
```

3. Pass a function to `CalculatorLayout`:

```
CalculatorLayout(
    buttonCallback:(text){ //<-- This is the text that the child(CalculatorButton) passes
    setState((){ //<--Rebuilds the home widget to display the updated text
        displayText += text; //<-- Joins the new text to the previous one
    });
  }
),
```

4. Finally display the text inside our `Text` widget

```
child: Text(
    displayText,
    ...
),
```

---

You'll see callbacks being used very often by many flutter widgets and are useful when the level is single. But as you can see this can get very messy for bigger apps and a better approach would be using `Provider` or `GetIt` along with `Notifier`.